Adding a SortDescription to a CollectionViewSource clears the view's filter
My code-behind builds a CollectionViewSource to sort and filter a collection of objects representing disk folders.  It exposes its View to my XAML.  I initially wrote the code to build the object like this
var cvsFolder       = new CollectionViewSource()
{
    Source = _scansSource.Items,
    View = { Filter = IsScan }     // Only show folders that are "scans"
};        

// Sort by desired property -- this clears out the filter
cvsFolder.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, dir));

But my filter was not working.  In my UI I was seeing all folders.
A bit of debugging showed that the issue was that my call to SortDescriptions.Add on the last line immediately clears out the filter that I just added a few lines above it.  (Either that or it completely replaces the view.  I am not sure which)
So I changed the order.  Like this
var cvsFolder = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = _scansSource.Items, };        
cvsFolder.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, dir));
cvsFolder.View.Filter = IsScan;   // Set the filter after adding sort descriptions

This works; My data is now sorted and filtered. but the behavior was unexpected, and slightly concerning.
Does this mean that if want to change my sorting dynamically  -- add or remove descriptions or change the directions -- as time goes on, I must reset the filter every time?   Are there other properties in the CollectionViewSource that might have similar affects or be similarly affected?
Or am I simply doing this the wrong way?

Use the SortDescriptions property of the View that you set the Filter property of. Then the order doesn't matter:
var cvsFolder = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = ... };
cvsFolder.View.Filter = ...;
cvsFolder.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, dir));

Or use the Filter event for the CollectionViewSource itself to filter the items:
private void CvsFolder_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = ...
}

But do not add sort descriptions to the view and filter the CollectionViewSource or vice versa.

Usually, you don't use a CollectionViewSource in C# code. Instead, you would access the ICollectionView directly. CollectionViewSource is a simple wrapper around the ICollectionView. It forwards all it's property values to the underlying ICollectionView. Obviously, it also resets the ICollectionView.Filter property.
The purpose of CollectionViewSource is to provide an API for XAML code to manage a ICollectionView. Since you can access it directly using C#, you don't need it.
In WPF when binding to a collection the binding engine creates a ICollectionView for the source collection and tracks it for changes to update the binding target. ItemsControl controls are essentially binding to the ICollectionView of a collection and not to the collection itself.
For this reason, you can modify the default ICollectionView e.g. by adding filtering and sorting and the ItemsControl will update accordingly (although the binding uses the collection as source). Sorting, filtering and grouping is only applied to the ICollectionView but not to the underlying collection.
// Let's assume a e.g. ListBox binds to the _scansSource.Items property.
// Then modifications of the default ICollectionView of _scansSource.Items 
// will be reflected in the ListBox:
var items = _scansSource.Items;

// For best performance make sure that the source collection is 
// an INotifyCollectionChanged implementation like an ObservableCollection.
ICollectionView itemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);

// The order is not relevant.
// However, you want to filter before sorting to improve the performance.
// Therefore the Filter property should be assigned 
// before adding a SortDescription or GroupDescription
itemsView.Filter = IsScan;
itemsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, dir));

If _scansSource is an ItemsControl, you can filter and sort it directly too:
itemsControl.Items.Filter = IsScan;
itemsControl.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, dir));

